# Validating a field in Blazor against service method/web API request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

Hello fellow programmers! :)

I've been playing recently with Blazor (server-side) and faced a little problem. I'm trying to validate a field against service method which is a simple HTTP request returning true/false. Think about the used/free username style check. The question is, what is the recommended way to make it in Blazor. Basically, I think about two solutions.

1. In a component with `EditForm` initialize own `EditContext` and `ValidationMessageStore` and then bind OnChange to a custom method which will execute the proper validation method and add a validation message in case of a problem.
2. Similar to the previous solution, but instead of making it inside the component (or a page) with `EditForm`, just create a custom component with `CascadingParameter` with `EditContext` and make it all the magic happen there.

Or the third one, a simpler version, which I don't know. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use FluentValidation, add a package reference to `PeterLeslieMorris.Blazor.FluentValidation`

Initialise it in the client `Startup`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddFormValidation(config =>
        {
            config
                .AddDataAnnotationsValidation()
                .AddFluentValidation(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
        });
    }
```

Your class to validate:

```
public class Person
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Create a fluent validator:

```
public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
{
    private readonly HttpClient HttpClient;

    public PersonValidator(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        HttpClient = httpClient;
        RuleFor(x => x.EmailAddress)
            .MustAsync(BeAvailable)
            .WithMessage("Email address is not available");
    }

    private Task<bool> BeAvailable(
        Person person,
        string emailAddress,
        PropertyValidatorContext context,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return HttpClient.PostJsonAsync<bool>("/Person/IsEmailAddressAvailable", new { EmailAddress = emailAddress });
    }
}
```

Your page to edit the view model:

```
@page "/"
@using ViewModels;

    <EditForm Model=Person>
        <PeterLeslieMorris.Blazor.Validation.Validate />
        Name <InputText @bind-Value=Person.Name /><br />
        <ValidationMessage For=@(() => Person.Name) /><br />
        <br/>
        Email <InputText @bind-Value=Person.EmailAddress /><br />
        <ValidationMessage For=@(() => Person.EmailAddress) /><br />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </EditForm>


@code {
    Person Person = new Person();
}
```

And finally, the server-side. We need a complex object with an EmailAddress property to satisfy the ASP MVC parameters criteria.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace BlazorApp13.Server.Controllers
{
    public class PersonController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public bool IsEmailAddressAvailable([FromBody]RequestWithEmailAddress request)
        {
            bool available = (request.EmailAddress ?? "").ToLowerInvariant().IndexOf("available.com") > -1;
            return available;
        }
    }

    public class RequestWithEmailAddress
    {
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*Known bug: Blazor doesn't officially support async validation - so the CSS status of the `InputText` component will not change between valid/invalid even though the validation message will appear/disappear. So you might want to hide the red/green visuals for this component using CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the project. I would go with number 2 if one or more of the followings are true:

- Do you need to reuse the same UI and logic else where in the application?
- Is is the page where you need to use this a complex page? Like has lots of parts that make the code less readable and maintainable without the component approach.
- Does other pages of your application break each smaller part into components? (Consistency is important)

Otherwise number one is fine. If the page grows in complexity over the time you can still refactor this part into a component.